# Why was Ondolindë always referred to as Gondolin?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, tolkien-languages

Did Tolkien ever say why Gondolin was so-called by its Sindarin name, instead of the Quenya: Ondolindë? Thingol forbade his people from using Quenya or responding to people who used it, as a response to the actions largely due to the Fëanorians, but the Elves of Gondolin, part of whom where Sindar, were led by  Turgon, a Noldo, and obviously had no contact with the rest of Beleriand. If I remember the timing correctly, the move by Turgon's people from Nevrast to Gondolin happened after the ban on Quenya, but I find it peculiar that Turgon didn't maintain the Quenya name of his kingdom. Clearly history is written by the dominant group etc etc, and almost everyone else was speaking Sindarin in the outside world, but Thingol wasn't around (or around for long) to enforce the name change once Gondolin became known to the rest of Beleriand.

> It is said that Turgon appointed its name to be Ondolindë in the speech of the Elves of Valinor, the Rock of the Music of Water, for there were fountains upon the hill; but in the Sindarin tongue the name was changed, and it became Gondolin, the Hidden Rock.

Aside from everything having multiple names in at least two languages, is there an *in universe* reason, or something from a letter explaining why the Sindarin name stuck?

Comment: Would an answer using primarily sources from the _History of Middle-earth_ be acceptable? Unfortunately, I think it's the only way I can think of answering this question.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Ondolinde is a Quenya word; Quenya was forbidden; ergo, Ondolinde was forbidden. QED.

Comment: @Edlothiad yes, it would!

Comment: Ok I'll get to work on an answer. @Martha Quenya was forbidden in _Doriath_ were Thingol was king. This question is asking about _Gondolin/Ondolinde_ were Turgon is King. Turgon's "native" language was Quenya. Turgon wouldn't be limited under the rules of Thingol.

Comment: @Martha but Quenya was forbidden _by Thingol in Beleriand_. Inside Gondolin, from whence no one (almost) went in or out, Turgon was king and could make his own rules and call the place whatever he wanted. Was he still bowing to Thingol's will when it had no force?

Comment: Well it took 2 hours and 20 minutes, but there you go.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Tolkien, a Translator

As I've stated [previously](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179900/68872), Tolkien envisioned himself, and the world around him, as part of Arda, and was therefore not an author creating a world, but a translator of histories written before him. The texts you read in *The Silmarillion* and *The Histories of Middle-earth* are translations (of translations) of the histories of Middle-earth recorded by the lore-masters of the Elves, Bilbo, Frodo and others. Given the likelihood that that these texts were translated from Sindarin to Westron/Old English, this is the likely reason for the use of the name Gondolin surviving to the modern day.

<sub>A map of the order works were written in, and the how the works influenced others will be provided at the bottom of this answer.</sub>

### Pengolodh and Ælfwine and early versions of the Legendarium

Pengolodh (*Q. Quendingoldo/Quengoldo*) was the greatest lore-master and chronicler in Middle-earth. Being born in Turgon's Nevrast, Pengolodh, of both Sindarin and Noldorin descent, migrated with the host to the hidden city of Gondolin. The Quenta Silmarillion was written by Pengolodh, although it is unclear whether he had written it in Sindarin or Quenya, it seems reasonable to guess that it would've been Sindarin, based on it being the common language he shared with the Teleri (the main inhabitants of Tol Eressëa). Furthermore, the recording of his name it its Sindarin form, seems to suggest a preference for the language in the recording of the histories.

> **Pengolodh, an  Elf  of  mixed  Sindarin  and  Noldorin  ancestry**,  born  in  Nevrast,  who  lived  in  Gondolin  from  its foundation.  **He wrote  both in Sindarin  and  in Quenya.** He  was  one  of  the  survivors  of  the  destruction  of  Gondolin,  from  which  he  rescued  a few  ancient  writings,  and  some  of  his  own  copies,  compilations,  and  commentaries.  It  is  due  to  this,  and to  his  prodigious  memory,  that  much  of  the  knowledge  of  the Elder Days was preserved.
> <sub>War of the Jewels - Quendi and Eldar: Appendix D</sub>

> For before  the  overthrow  of  Morgoth  and  the  ruin  of  Beleriand,  he  collected  much  material  among  the  survivors  of  the  wars  at  Sirion's  Mouth  concerning  languages  and  gesture-systems  with  which,  owing  to  the  isolation  of  Gondolin,  he  had not  before  had any direct  acquaintance.  Pengolodh  is  said  to  have  remained  in  Middle-earth  until  far  on  into  the  Second  Age  for  the  further-ance  of  his enquiries,  and  for a while  to  have dwelt  among the Dwarves  of  Casarrondo  (Khazad-dum).
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

Ælfwine (Eriol), an English-man who had found his way to Tol Eresseä around 900 AD, was the latest translator of the works, and it was him who'd brought the works or the tales back to Britain. Ælfwine spent what may have been years on Tol Eressëa learning the tales taught to him by Pengolodh and at some point had translated the Quenta Silmarillion. It is again unclear whether he'd learnt Sindarin or Quenya, however as before it is likely, due to his being on Tol Eressëa, that he'd been taught to read the Sindarin writings of Pengolodh and learnt to speak Sindarin. As such, his translations into Old English would likely have preserved the Sindarin name for Gondolin.

> These  histories  were  written  by  Pengolod  the  Wise  of  Gondolin,  both  in  that  city  before  its  fall,   and  afterwards  at  Tathrobel  in the Lonely  Isle, Toleressëa,  after the return unto the West.  In their making he used much the writings of  Rumil  the Elfsage  of  Valinor,  chiefly  in the annals of  Valinor and the account  of  tongues,  and  he  used  also  the  accounts  that  are  preserved in the Golden Book. **The work of Pengolod I  learned  much  by  heart,  and  turned  into  my tongue**,  some  during  my  sojourn  in  the  West,  but  most  after  my  return  to  Britain.
> <sub>The Lost Road and other Writings - Quenta Silmarillion</sub>

### Bilbo's "Translations from the Elvish"

During the time of *The Lord of the Rings*, Tolkien's histories were (again) in turmoil. Ælfwine likely remained a part of the stories, however as opposed to him being the source for the Ainulindalë, Valaquenta and the Quenta Silmarillion, that task seemed to have fallen to Bilbo. In the Red Book, Bilbo had included the "Translations from the Elvish", which were known to contain at least the Ainulindalë and the Valaquenta and likely contained the Silmarillion. In this case, Bilbo was known (and Elrond) to speak Sindarin. In this version, it would've been clear that the name Gondolin would've been used in Bilbo's translations, as Elrond would likely have recorded the events in his native Sindarin, and if the texts were written in Quenya, the speakers of the Old tongues that Bilbo had around him would've translated into the Sindarin for him.

> Quenta Silmarillion was no doubt one of Bilbo's Translations from the Elvish, preserved in the Red Book of Westmarch.
> <sub>The Complete Guide to Middle-earth - Quenta Silmarillion</sub>

> and he gave him also  three  books  of  lore  that  he  had  made  at  various  times,  written  in  his spidery  hand, and  labelled on  their  red backs: *Translations  from  the  Elvish,  by B.B.*
> <sub>The Return of the King - Book 6, Chapter IX: Many Partings</sub>

> But the chief importance of Findegil’s copy is that it alone
> contains the whole of Bilbo’s ‘Translations from the Elvish’. These three volumes were found to be a work of great skill and learning in which, between 1403 and 1418, he had used all the sources available to him in Rivendell, both living and written. But since they were little used by Frodo, being almost entirely concerned with the Elder Days, no more is said of them here.
> <sub>The Fellowship of the Rings - Note on the Shire Records</sub>

---

This map is taken from the excellent resource [The Chroniclers of Arda](http://www.forodrim.org/gobennas/chron_en.html#red)

```
Key:  

" " = Important Work,        * * = Author  
( ) = Translations,          _ _ = Regions  
 >  = Direction of flow

                      *Quennar i Onótimo*
                  "Of the Beginning of Time..."
                        "Yénonótië"
                    "The Tale of Years"
          *Rúmil*            |                     "Parma Culuina"
      "Annals of Aman"---<---|          _Doriath_         |
        "Ambarcanta"         |      "The Grey Annals"     |
       "Ainulindalë"         |              |             |
             |               |              | *Pengolodh* |            *Dírhaval*
             |--------->-----+----->----"Quenta Silmarillion"--<--"Narn i Chîn Húrin"
             |                                "Lammas"
             |                                    |
             |----------------<-------------------+
             |
             |------------>--------+--------->--------+
             |                     |                  |
             |                 _Númenor_         _Rivendell_               
             |             "Indis i·Ciryamo"   "Books of Lore"
             |                     |                  |
             |                     |                  |
             |             _Arnor and Gondor_         |
             |                     |                  |          *Bilbo Baggins*  
             |            "Book of the Kings"         |            "My Diary"
             |          "Book of the Stewards"        +-("Translations from the Elvish")
             |               "Akallabêth"                               |
"Quentalë    |  *Torhir Ifant*     |              *Frodo Baggins*       |
Ardanómion"  | "Dorgannas Iaur"    |                *Sam Gamgee*        |
    |        |       |             |----->----"The Lord of the Rings"   |
    |        |       |             |                        |           |
    |        |       |             |                       "The Red Book of Westmarch"
    |        |       |             |         *Findegil*                 |
    |        |       |             |-->--"The Thain's Book"------<------|
    |        |       |             |             |                [Many copies]     _The Shire_
    |   *Ælfwine*    |             |             |                      |       "The Tale of Years"
  ("Quenta Silmarillion")          |             +----------->----------|               |
     ("Annals of Aman")            |                                    |               |
      ("Grey Annals")              |                                    |               |
             |                     |                                    |               |
             +-------->------------|-------------------<----------------+-------<-------+
                                   |
                           *J. R. R. Tolkien*
                             ("The Hobbit")
                        ("The Lord of the Rings")
                          ("The Silmarillion")
```

Comment: Not as much evidence as I'd hoped there'd be for my arguments, but they remain valid none-the-less. There's various vague hints in the WJ, LRW and MR which suggest writings being in one language or another, but chronicling those would require a larger character limit than I am allowed.

Comment: WJ = War of the Jewels, MR=Morgoth's Ring, LRW=Lost Road and other Writings? As usual, an innocent question leads to a really, really interesting question: in what language was the Quenta originally written, in-universe? If you ever find good evidence, please add it. It's not urgent :-)

Comment: @DavidRoberts I will keep a keen eye on the FoG, while I highly doubt any new information will come up there, I'm still interested. But yes, the key point to answering your question is indeed "What language was the QS or FoG originally written in?", an even deeper study who look at who wrote it, but that might be for another time. I will also hopefully have a chance to see the exhibition at the Bodelian, might be some hidden info there.

Comment: Just when I start to get a fat head about my understanding of Tolkien I get properly humbled by an answer like this. Thank you! -- I also note how interesting it is that Tolkien's 'verse allows for such expansive in-universe answers without becoming ad hoc or hand-wavy. The dude was truly brilliant.

Comment: @user23715 The BoLT is a very slow and very dreary read. I hadn’t been able to continue with the HoME after that, only being able to read snippets at a time

Comment: +1 I wish I could give +1million.  This is one of my favorite answers on this entire site!

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach can I ask what about this answer you thought made it so worthy?

Comment: @Edlothiad, the research, definitely, but the editorial voice especially. It has the feel of a proper scholarly article on the subject.  I enjoyed reading it as much or more than most of the HoME. As user23715 pointed out, this answer really points out why we love the world that Prof Tolkien created. If someone were to ask me why I am so obsessed with Tolkien's creations (and why I feel the movies are so lacking), I feel like I could point to this answer.

Comment: @Quasi_Stomach that means a lot, thanks.

Comment: There's also the matter that the name Gondolin was retained from the earliest versions of the mythology, where the city was founded by Gnoldorin exiles speaking Gnomish. Out-of-universe, the language that was Gnomish became Sindarin, and the speakers of that language switched from being the exiles from Aman to the natives of Beleriand. I imagine Tolkien preferred to keep the name, and wrote the newer versions of the story in a way to explain the use of Sindarin rather than Quenya for the name of the city.

Comment: I was disappointed that you.spelled Pengoloð with "dh".

Comment: @Spencer simply how my copies of the _War of the Jewels_ has it written, and how the Chronicles of Arda had it written.

Answer (score 13):

The Noldor had arrived to Middle-earth after the First Kinslaying, and when Thingol learnt of the latter he banned the use of Quenyan throughout his realm. This rule took place many years before Turgon sent his people to live in the secret valley, and so *The Silmarillion* says that the Sindar refused to use Quenya, and the Noldor adopted it into their everyday speech.

However, when Tuor first arrives at Gondolin, he hears:

> And even as the echoes died in the stone, Tuor heard out of the heart of darkness a voice speak in the Elven-tongues: first in the High Speech of the Noldor, which he knew not; and then in the tongue of Beleriand, though in a manner somewhat strange to his ears, as of a people long sundered from their kin.
>
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales, Of Tuor And His Coming To Gondolin*</sub>

Further reinforced by a side-note accompanying the chapter:

> In *The Silmarillion* nothing is said specifically concerning the speech of the Elves of Gondolin; but this passage suggests that for some of them the High Speech (Quenya) was in ordinary use. **It is stated in a late linguistic essay that Quenya was in daily use in Turgon's house, and was the childhood speech of Eärendil; but that 'for most of the people of Gondolin it had become a language of books, and as the other Noldor they used Sindarin in daily speech'**. The Silmarillion: after the edict of Thingol 'the Exiles took the Sindarin tongue in all their daily uses, and the High Speech of the West was spoken only by the lords of the Noldor among themselves. Yet that speech lived ever as a language of lore, wherever any of that people dwelt.'

Finally, in *The History of Middle-earth*:

> His (Earendil) names were, however, given in Quenya; for Turgon after his foundation of the secret city of Gondolin had re-established Quenya as the daily speech of his household.
>
> <sub>*The History of Middle-earth, Book 12, Peoples of Middle-earth, The Shibboleth of Fëanor*</sub>

#### In-universe

Gondolin, to the other Elves, was known as Gondolin. Thingol's ban on Quenyan was taken seriously throughout Beleriand. However, within Gondolin itself it was called Ondolindë — his kingdom, his rule.

#### Out-of-universe

*The Silmarillion* used the Sindarized form of Ondolindë probably to prevent confusion to readers throughout the book. Constant switching between Ondolindë and Gondolin would have been hard to read. Even though Quenyan was still used within Ondolindë, its usage in Beleriand had severely dropped, even after Thingol's death.

It would stand to reason that it would be more appropriate to write a book in a language that is still used and understood by majority of the people, instead of a language that had, in the past, been shunned and now, is mostly forgotten.

Comment: Thingol was the King of Doriath, and claimed the High kingship of all the Sindarin Elves in all Beleriand, as well as of everyone else who settled in Beleriand.  But I don't know if Gondolin was within the usual borders of Beleriand.  And Turgon was the king of his Noldorin and Sindarin followers, and for a period he was also the High King of the Noldor in Middle-earth, and so may have considered himself at least Thingol's equal.  I can imagine that Turgon might have reacted to Thingol's tyrannical decree by decreeing that all his followers must speak only Noldorin, not Sindarin.

Comment: @Mat in principle the in-universe author(s) of the _Quenta Silmarillion_ could have consciously translated Quenya names systematically to Sindarin, but it is known that lore was recorded and transmitted in Quenya among the Noldor, which would point to a Sindarin authorship, which is a bit odd, considering the massive focus on the Noldor (and including their time in Aman). So both answers would be interesting, I think.

Comment: @DavidRoberts [this post on the TolkienForums](http://www.thetolkienforum.com/index.php?threads/who-wrote-the-silmarillion.23582/#post-517003) may be useful regarding the in-u authorship of *The Silmarillion*

Answer (score 3):

Sindarin was the universal language of Beleriand. It seems that History, for its own reasons, recorded names or persons, places and events in Sindarin, although other languages and dilects existed.

As per the precious answers, Gondolin was a place were Quenya could be spoken freely. Even so, it seems that Gondolin was a bilingual society, and Quenya was only use for lore and in the royal household, so Sindarin was still a more powerful language.

It is also notable that in the linguistics of Middle-earth, its inhabitants liked to adapt and translate names, and they avoided language switching. That is why the Noldor Sindarinized their names, and that's how they were recorded. While praising Frodo and Sam, they translated (on-the-fly) their names to Sindarin, as "Daur" and "Perhael".

That being said it seems that "Ondolinde" was a doomed term, becaue it was used only in Turgon's household and books, and "Gondolin" was destined to prevail everywhere else: Sindarin was the language of lore of Gondor in the Third Age, so the city was remembered ever after as Gondolin.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly everything in the legendarium had diverse names, in diverse languages.  For example, the inhabitants of Gondolin (the Gondolithlim) knew it thus:

> Rejoice that ye have found it, for behold before you the City of Seven
> Names where all who war with Morgoth may find hope."
>
> Then said Tuor: "What be those names?" And the chief of the Guard made
> answer: "'Tis said and 'tis sung: '*Gondobar* am I called and
> *Gondothlimbar*, City of Stone and City of the Dwellers in Stone; *Gondolin* the Stone of Song and *Gwarestrin* am I named, the Tower of Guard, *Gar Thurion* or the Secret Place, for I am hidden from the
> eyes of Morgoth; but they who love me most greatly call me *Loth*, for
> like a flower am I, even *Lothengriol* the flower that blooms on the
> plain.' Yet," said he, "in our daily speech we speak and we name it
> mostly Gondolin." Then said Voronwe: "Bring us thither, for we fain
> would enter," and Tuor said that his heart desired much to tread the
> ways of that fair city.

From The Fall of Gondolin, The Lost Tales

So, not *always* Gondolin!

Comment: A good reminder. But also, at this point in the development of the Legendarium, what later developed into Sindarin was the language of the Gnomes/Noldoli ("Gnomish" or "Goldogrin"), and it was they who founded Gondolin after the Battle of Unnumbered Tears. The Noldoli did not speak Qenya, so the names need no explanation. The later idea of the Noldor needing to stop speaking Quenya due to Thingol's ban, and adopt Sindarin, is what is happening here.

Comment: I think you can put that down to translation at a later date by Pengolod or some mannish source.  Any guesses what the Seven Names would be in Noldorin? ;)

Comment: Well, there's this https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Gondolin#The_Seven_Names but those are Qenya. I don't know enough to generate neo-Noldorin! I'd be happier just seeing the seven names in Sindarin.

Comment: Ah OK - I don't use TG unless someone points me there, I got the quote from the book ;)

Comment: It cites Parma Eldalamberon 13, which I personally don't have, and I can't assume others do either ;)